# Is there a way to create this kind of table on MS Access?

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, report, relational-database

everyone.

I'm building a system to manage data and Im using Microsoft Access. I've built the database with its tables and relationships. Now I need to create reports or summaries that allow me to display the data stored under certain criteria, like this:

[image: Apparently, stackoverflow doesn't allow me to put images, so here is the link.]

The data behing this report is a table that contains a list of applicants, their acceptance status, among other data.

I need to count how many applicants are by year, how many were accepted, how many of them where registered that year, and the acceptance rate by year.

I've tried using query designer but it doesn't provide me what I need, although I think I need to do a query by each column but I believe there is a simpler way.

Is there an efficient way to do it? Should I try vba?

Thanks!

Comment: seems like this can be done in a query with the `count` aggregate function..., but really it depends on how your source data is structured.

Comment: Build a report and use its Sorting & Grouping features with aggregate calcs in textboxes. Report allows display of detail data as well as summary calcs. Rather basic Access functionality.

Comment: A better title for this question might help others as well

Comment: what you want is a cross-tab query.  here is a first link to get you started: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8.